# python how to loop through csv several times from top?

Tags: python, loops, csv

I have a csv file (yy.csv) that looks like this:

```
term,country,score,week
aa,USA,26.17,11/22/15-11/28/15
bb,USA,16.5,11/15/15-11/21/15
cc,UK,31.36,11/22/15-11/28/15
dd,UK,21.24,11/15/15-11/21/15
ee,FR,19.2,11/22/15-11/28/15
```

I also have a list called country_list:

```
country_list=['USA','UK','FR']
```

I am looping through the CSV file for each country in the country list to get the term value if country in country list == col2 and week == 11/22/15-11/28/15.

Here is my code:

```
with open("yy.csv") as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    next(reader, None)
    for index,country in enumerate(country_list):
        print country
        last_week_dict[country] = []
        for reader_row in reader:
            if ((reader_row[1] == country) and (reader_row[3] == "11/22/15-11/28/15")):
                last_week_dict[country].append(reader_row[0])
            else:
                continue

        print last_week_dict[country]
```

The output i should be getting from the `print` statement:

```
last_week_dict['USA']=['aa']
last_week_dict['UK']=['cc']
last_week_dict['FR']=['ee']
```

However i only got value appended to the USA key:

```
last_week_dict['USA']=['aa']
last_week_dict['UK']=[]
last_week_dict['FR']=[]
```

Could it be because when i loop through the csv file, it doesnt start from the top of the file after it goes through USA?

Answer (score 2):

Your suspicion is correct: the `reader` object is an iterator, and iterators may only be read in the forward direction. They can't be reset.

You can avoid doing two loops from the file - it seems that your goal is to make sure that you get data for the specific countries. However, you can make sure that happens in a single loop:

```
import collections
import csv

# If this were a much longer collection of items it
# would be better to use a set than a list.
country_list = ['USA', 'UK', 'FR']

# The defauldict(list) allows us to just start appending
# rather than checking whether the key is already in the
# dict.
last_week_dict = collections.defaultdict(list)

with open('yy.csv') as infile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile)
    __ = next(reader)  # Skip the header
    for term, country, score, week in reader:
        if country not in country_list:
            continue
        if week != '11/22/15-11/28/15':
            continue
        last_week_dict[country].append(term)

print(last_week_dict)
```

Comment: is __ a valid variable name in python? Or is it just a handy way to throw away the first row?

Comment: Yes it's valid, and yes it's handy for that reason. But it's not strictly necessary.

Comment: may i know what this part mean? `if country not in country_list` All the country values i have in the csv file is in the country_list. How do we make sure that if country in csv file = country in current loop of country match, then append to dict? Im just wondering why you took out `for index,country in enumerate(country_list):`

Comment: I thought you were using the `country_list` to make sure you only got data for the given countries. However, you seem to have been using it because you thought that you have to fill in `last_week_dict` one country at a time. That's not necessary; the single loop populates all of the countries just fine.

Comment: so say we go through the csv file and we are at `country = FR`. I need to make sure that the country list loop is also on 'FR' and not just if FR in list. i dont just want to make sure that if any of my countries are in the list. i need to make sure that `current country in csv == current country in list`.

Comment: This is because i have other parts below this code snippet that makes use of the `country` loop so i really need country to be exact instead if it exist.

Comment: Hence i need to loop through the csv file many times from the top to satisfy each country's requirements. i suppose your code doesnt iterate from the top each time?

Comment: My code loops through the CSV file once and saves the results. You can print `last_week_dict` at the bottom of the loop to see what it's doing.

Comment: If you have other code below the loop shown in your question, you can move the `with open()...` and such inside the loop. But I think that would be terribly ineffecient.